# Pyspark trained Logistic Regression model doesn't predict() and predictProbability() function

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I trained a Logistic Regression model with PySpark MLlib built-in class `LogisticRegression`. However, when it was trained, it couldn't be used to predict other dataframes because `AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'predictProbability'` OR `AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'predict'`.

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
model = LogisticRegression(regParam=0.5, elasticNetParam=1.0)

# define the input feature & output column
model.setFeaturesCol('features')
model.setLabelCol('WinA')

model.fit(df_train)

model.setPredictionCol('WinA')
model.predictProbability(df_val['features'])
model.predict(df_val['features'])
```

```
AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'predictProbability'
```

**Properties:**

PySpark version:

```
>>import pyspark
>>pyspark.__version__
3.1.2
```

JDK version:

```
>>!java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Environment: Google Colab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code here

```
model.fit(df_train)
```

did not actually give you a trained model since the type of variable `model` is still `pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression` class

```
type(model)

# pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
```

So, you should catch the returned object by assigning it to a variable or overwriting your `model` variable, then it will give you the trained logistic regression model of `pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel` class

```
model = model.fit(df_train)
type(model)

# pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel
```

Finally, `.predict` and `.predictProbability` methods need an argument of a `pyspark.ml.linalg.DenseVector` object. So, I think you want to use `.transform` instead since it will add predicted label and probability as columns to the input dataframe. It would be like this

```
predicted_df = model.transform(df_val)
```